# Is there a way to change static cell height with uibutton?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uibutton, row-height

I have UIViewController with static cells in two sections and I want to change height of one row with the button. My only idea was to do something with

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 {
    return 88
    }
    else {
    return 44
    }
}
```

but I don't think I can assign it to UIButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable for staticCellHeight
and return this variable instead of 88

create an action for UIButton

change the value of the variable in the action

call tableview.reloadData()